# Difference between read on and read about

Tags: meaning, word-choice, postposition

Very often my co-workers ask me the question:

> What are you doing?

And I always wonder whether I should reply with *reading on* or *reading about* :

> I am reading **about** the origins of the universe.
>
> I am reading **on** the origins of the universe.

Can I use **read on** and **read about** interchangeably?

Comment: *read on* means to continue reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct preposition there is *about*: I am reading about a subject.

We also have the phrasal verb *to read up*, which is informal and means to study, or become more familiar with something.  *Read up* uses *on*: I'm reading up on that subject.